# Integral test without the assumption of monotonicity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f: R \to R$ be a continues and non-negative  s.t.
$\lim _{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$

> I.  If the series $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}f(n)$ convergent then the integral $\int_{k}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx $ is convergent .
>
> II. If the integral $\int_{k}^{\infty} f(x) \,dx$ is convergent then the series $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}f(n)$ convergent.

I know those are some of the conditions to the integral test, but I don't have any information if $f(x)$ is monotonic decreasing. Please help me to prove or find counter-example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the condition that $f(x)$ be monotonic, this is untrue. As a hint: try to find a function which is $0$ at every natural number but such that

$$ \int_n^{n + 1} f(x) \, dx = \frac1n$$

or possibly some scalar multiple of this.

Then
$$ \sum_{n \ge 1} f(n) = 0$$
but
$$ \int_1^\infty f(x) \,dx = \sum_{n \ge 1} \int_n^{n + 1} f(x) \, dx = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac1n = \infty. $$

You will likely find that it will be easier to start with a picture.

---

Here is an example of such a function.

[image: img]

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{n} (x - n) & \text{if }n \le x < n + \frac12 \\
-\frac{2}{n} (x - (n + 1)) & \text{if } n + \frac12 \le x < n + 1
\end{cases}
$$
where $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ [(Here is an interactive version.)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ytujtm9ama) This is a sequence of triangles with height $2/n$ and width $1$. So the area over the interval $[n, n+ 1]$ is $\frac12 \mathrm{base} \times \mathrm{height} = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I found that $\frac{sin^2(\pi x)}{x}$ is good example for section I.
but what about section II ?

Comment: @ofir.nir $\sin^2(\pi x)/x$ is good but hard to integrate. You can approximate it by triangles to make the integration easier. For section II do it the opposite way. Make $f(n) = 1/n$ and then in each interval $[n,n + 1]$ make the function a "u" shape so that the integral is small.

Comment: I tried to write it down but I can't find a non-negative function so it's integral is $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @ofir.nir Do you want me to give you a function?

Comment: I don't think I would find it myself :(

Comment: @ofir.nir I've edited it into the answer. You will notice that the formula is a bit complicated, which is why I recommended drawing a picture first.